# Why does props keep reappearing as a parameter on my Home function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm creating an app and on my index.tsx file I keep getting this error on "props" `'props' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133) Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)`

This is my code:

```
import { SignIn, SignInButton, SignOutButton, useUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";

import { api } from "~/utils/api";

export default function Home(props){
  const hello = api.example.hello.useQuery({ text: "from tRPC" });

  const user = useUser();

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>My app</title>
        <meta name="description" content="New to this" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-center bg-gradient-to-b from-[#2e026d] to-[#15162c]">
      <div>
        {!user.isSignedIn && <SignInButton />}
        {!!user.isSignedIn && <SignOutButton />}
      </div>
       <SignIn path="/sign-in" routing="path" signUpUrl="/sign-up" /> 
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Although while deleting props gets rid of the error, when I save the file it just reappears. (Also tried assigning it a value by writing `props: any` and

```
interface TestProps {
  title?: string
}

const defaultProps: TestProps = {
  title: '.'
}

export default function Home(props = defaultProps) {
```

Comment: What IDE are you using? Which extensions do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 warnings in the error message that you posted, which are thrown by Typescrip linter --

> `'props' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)`

This is just a warning & for best practice as well. You can either start using this variable and this will automatically go away. Or, if you know what you are doing and doesn't like to see this kind of error, you can add the following rule in your `tsconfig.json` file

```json
{
  ...other configs 
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...other configs
    "noUnusedLocals": false,   // <-- This one
  }
}
```

More info -- https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUnusedLocals

> `Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)`

Same as the previous one - this also is just a warning & for best practice. Like the message says, you can explicitly assign the variable `props` a type then the error would go away, or you could

```json
{
  ...other configs 
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...other configs
    "noImplicitAny": false,   // <-- This one
  }
}
```

More info about it -- https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny

As annoying as it seems, both rules are encouraged to be enabled (as they already are by default) to help catch any potential bugs during development.

If you want to keep them enabled, you should assign the type to the `props` like so instead.

```
export default function Home(props: TestProps) {
  // ...
  // you code here
  // ...
  console.log(props) // also use the variable `props` somehow. This is just an example
}
```